# RedisInsight on Docker and Redis on Docker: Could not connect: Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, docker-container, redisinsights

Based on this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrFeRwJjWHI , I tried running Redis in Docker.

File `docker-compose.yml`

```yml
version: "3.8"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

```
docker pull redis
docker-compose up
docker-compose up -d
docker container ls
telnet localhost 6379
```

Telnet, type `PING` then press Enter key (you will not see text), then see result: `PONG`. Type `quit` to exit.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.508]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\docker>docker-compose stop redis
Stopping docker_redis_1 ... done

D:\docker>
```

See what is running

```
docker container ls
```

You will see, docker redis was stoped.

```
docker image prune -a
docker-compose up
```

Docker RedisInsight

```
docker run -v redisinsight:/db -p 8001:8001 redislabs/redisinsight:latest
```

Wait about 6 minutes (at internet speed at 22:30) for downloading, unzip, install, starting.

go to: http://localhost:8001/ (auto open web browser). Health check for RedisInsight http://localhost:8001/healthcheck/ is OK.

[image]

[image]

[image]

(I also noted at here https://donhuvy.github.io/redis/docker/2020/10/10/run-redis-on-docker.html )

How to connect RedisInsight with Redis without error?

Update: This is my host file, seemly have problem at here (IP `127.0.0.1` for Kubernetes, really I don't know about Kubernetes, I am learning it.), but I don't know how to fix.

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1    www.techsmith.com
127.0.0.1    activation.cloud.techsmith.com
127.0.0.1    oscount.techsmith.com
127.0.0.1    updater.techsmith.com
127.0.0.1    camtasiatudi.techsmith.com
127.0.0.1    tsccloud.cloudapp.net
127.0.0.1    assets.cloud.techsmith.com

# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.1.44 host.docker.internal
192.168.1.44 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

Comment: Are these containers running in the same network? Try to list the networks and the containers to see if these are on the same network

Comment: How to list the networks and the containers?

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: I am not sure .

Comment: you can do the following to list networks with docker: `docker network ls`. 

to check the network of your container you can do the following: 
`$ docker inspect c1 -f "{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks }}"`
c1 == the name of the container.

Comment: I catch error https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/95754071-b5ecf880-0ccc-11eb-9da0-e591ebe6c121.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RedisInsight are trying to connect to container's localhost. Try typing `127.0.0.1` into `Host` field.

If file host has been changed like the updated information in question, use `192.168.1.44` .

Comment: It still error https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/95660345-68984c00-0b51-11eb-8f2d-60ea97a970e3.png . I hope you can help me.

Comment: This is my host file https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/32aaf97a4e3e8b7cdacec53aab04d31d#file-hosts-txt-L35 seemly have problem at this IP. Let's me know how to fix.

Comment: @DoNhuVy according to your hosts file the IP address you are looking for is: `192.168.1.44`

Answer (score 11):

Using this setup in `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  redis:
    image: 'redis:6.0.6'
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:6379:6379/tcp'
    volumes:
      - 'redis_data:/data:rw'
    healthcheck:
      test: redis-cli ping
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  redisinsight:
    image: 'redislabs/redisinsight:latest'
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:8001:8001'
```

you can access redis via

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Since you haven't mentioned any network for the containers, they are conneted to the *default bridge* network. [learn more](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#:%7E:text=When%20you%20start%20Docker%2C%20a,to%20the%20default%20bridge%20network.)

To get container IP address

*Type in your terminal*

```sh
# Check container network IP address

docker container inspect -f "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" <container name>
```

Use the IP address in: http://localhost:8001/ (RedisInsight).

or

(Not Recommended) Type the `IP address` of your HOST machine will solve the problem

Use `ipconfig` or `ifconfig` based on your OS to get your IP

Answer (score 5):

For your containers to access each other you should first connect them to same network.

```
docker network create redis
docker network connect redis elastic_diffie
docker network connect redis docker_redis_1
```

After that open RedisInsight UI  and write `docker_redis_1` to your Hostand keep the port same. You should be able to connect to your redis container.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a little late to this one, but you can just use the docker host loopback

host.docker.internal - this will resolve to the host ip

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you must put your Ip by ipconfig instead of localhost